# Matching / Mapping lists with elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

There is a list in mongodb,
eg:

```
db_name = "Test"
collection_name = "Map"
db.Map.findOne()

{
  "_id" : ObjectId(...),
  "Id" : "576",
  "FirstName" : "xyz",
  "LastName" : "abc",
  "skills" : [
               "C++",
               "Java",
               "Python",
               "MongoDB",
             ]
}
```

There is a list in elastcisearch index (I am using kibana to execute queries)

```
GET /user/_search

{
  "took" : 31,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 7,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "customer",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "5",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "xyz abc"  
          "Age" : 21,
          "skills" : [
                        "C++",
                        "Java",
                        "Python",
                        "MongoDB", 
                     ]  
        }
      }, 
     ]
    }
}
```

Can anyone help with the elasticsearch query that will match both the records based on skills. 
I am using python to write the code

If a match is found, I am trying to get the first name and last name of that user

```
First name : "xyz"
Last name : "abc"
```

Comment: Which two records you want to be matched and based on what skills? Are both the records indexed in elastic search? What is the mapping on index? Please be more clear on these.

Comment: One record is in mongodb and other in elasticsearch 
I want to match both the records based on entire list of skills. If the entire list of skills match then only return the first name and last name

Comment: Mongodb and elasticsearch are entirely different in terms of schema, storage, way of querying etc. Both the records should to be in elasticsearch index so that they can be queried on.

Comment: Assuming that both records are in same elastic search index, what would be the query for matching both records based on entire list of skills

Comment: Just a clarification; all the skills should match or any of the given skills?

Comment: All the skills should match.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are indexing all the document in elastic and of these you want to match documents where `skills` has both `java` and `mongodb` the query will be as:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "skills": "mongodb"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "skills": "java"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Kiran: Has this helped you?